# How to pass values between two apex:selectList asynchronously

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, actionfunction

I'm building a VF that's meant to query for `Thing__c`. The fields that are meant to be filtered are set in a fieldset. I'm iterating the fieldset rendering an `apex:inputField` for each and have an instance of `Thing__c` in the controller to capture the values of each filter.

For picklists I need to be able to filter for more than one value even if they're single selection picklists so I had to write a custom component that displays two `selectList` and two buttons in the middle to move options from one list to another like the ones you see when selecting the fields to show in a new list view.

The custom component:

```
<apex:component >

    <apex:attribute name="filter" description="Filter object" type="PicklistFilter" />
    <apex:attribute name="fieldName" description="Name of the field" type="String" />

    <apex:actionRegion><apex:outputPanel layout="block">
        <div style="display: table;">
            <div style="display: table-row;">

                <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;">
                    <apex:selectList id="optionsList" size="3" value="{! filter.incoming }" style="min-width: 100px"
                        multiselect="true">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{! filter.options }" />
                    </apex:selectList>
                </div>

                <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;">
                    <apex:commandButton value="<<" onclick="removeSelections('{! fieldName }')"
                        rerender="optionsList, selectedList" /><br />
                    <apex:commandButton value=">>" onclick="addSelections('{! fieldName }')"
                        rerender="optionsList, selectedList" />
                </div>

                <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;">
                    <apex:selectList id="selectedList" size="3" value="{! filter.outgoing }" style="min-width: 100px"
                        multiselect="true">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{! filter.selected }" />
                    </apex:selectList>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </apex:outputPanel></apex:actionRegion>

</apex:component>
```

Which is inside this section of the page:

```
<apex:repeat value="{! $ObjectType.Thing__c.FieldSets.FiltersFieldset }"
    var="field">
    <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
        <apex:outputlabel value="{! $ObjectType.Thing__c.fields[field.fieldPath].Label }"/>
        <apex:outputPanel layout="block">
            <apex:variable var="type" value="{! $ObjectType['Thing__c'].fields[field.fieldPath].Type }"/>
            <apex:variable var="picklist" value="{! type == 'picklist' || type == 'multipicklist' }"/>
            <apex:variable var="date" value="{! type == 'date' || type == 'datetime' }" />
            <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{! NOT(picklist) }">
                <!-- regular input field -->
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <span style="{! IF(picklist,'','display: none;') }">
                <c:picklistFilter filter="{! picklistFilters[field.fieldPath] }" fieldName="{! field.fieldPath }" />
            </span>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
</apex:repeat>
```

`addSelections` and `addSelections` are defined as `actionFunction` with a param outside of the iteration of the fields:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="addSelections" action="{! addSelections }" rerender="filters">
    <apex:param name="picklistFieldToUpdate" assignTo="{! picklistFieldToUpdate }" value="?" />
</apex:actionFunction>
<apex:actionFunction name="removeSelections" action="{! removeSelections }" rerender="filters">
    <apex:param name="picklistFieldToUpdate" assignTo="{! picklistFieldToUpdate }" value="?" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

`picklistFilters` is a map in my controller that maps instances of this class:

```
public class PicklistFilter {
    private List<SelectOption> options;
    private List<SelectOption> selected;
    public List<String> incoming {get;set;}
    public List<String> outgoing {get;set;}

    public PicklistFilter(List<SelectOption> values) {
        options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.addAll(values);
        selected = new List<SelectOption>();
        incoming = new List<String>();
        outgoing = new List<String>();
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public PageReference addSelections() {
        for (String s : incoming) {
            selected.add(new SelectOption(s, s));
            remove(s, options);
        }
        incoming = new List<String>();
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference removeSelections() {
        for (String s : outgoing) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(s, s));
            remove(s, selected);
        }
        outgoing = new List<String>();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The `addSelections` and `removeSelections` methods of the controller call the corresponding ones (named the same) in the `PicklistFilter` instance for a specific field

The problem with this solution is that it seems to randomly malfunction. When I move one value from the left list to the right one, generally it works. Or viceversa. But at times whatever it moves from a side to the other, it takes it back to the origin list just after it was moved.

[image: This is how it behaves]

Why is it this quirky? Feel free to ask for more code.

Comment: how you have defined `picklistFieldToUpdate` in controller?

Comment: @SantanuBoral String property. By debugging I've not found irregularities on its values. I mean, the correct picklist filter is selected to have its selections moved.

Comment: I can see String property of `incoming` and `outgoing`, not `picklistFieldToUpdate`

Comment: @SantanuBoral I've not pasted any of my controller code here. In third code block you'll see referenced the controller property named picklistFieldToUpdate.

Comment: Don't you this would be easy to do using Jquery plugins? a quick google search I found this plugin which I liked : http://crlcu.github.io/multiselect/examples/zero-configuration.html

Comment: @Rao how would I have the Apex controller receive the values that are in the list at the right?

Comment: If you can't get yours working, you might consider moving to https://github.com/metadaddy/Visualforce-Multiselect-Picklist which AFAIK works reliably.